# Jenkins - How to pass variables to Bitbucket status notify plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to pass variables to Bitbucketstatusnotify plugin but it's not working. I have tried different iterations and using escape characters etc to no avail. Is this even possible ? If yes, how ?

My jenkins pipeline snippet below:

```
REPO_SLUG = sh(script: "echo ${GIT_URL} | grep -oP '(?<=/).*[^.git]'", returnStdout: true)

// Update Bitbucket commit build status to In Progress  
bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'INPROGRESS', repoSlug: "${REPO_SLUG}", commitId: "${GIT_COMMIT}")

try {

//build code here

// Update Bitbucket commit build status to Successful  
bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'SUCCESSFUL', repoSlug: "${REPO_SLUG}", commitId: "${GIT_COMMIT}")


} catch (Exception e) {

echo 'Error occured: ' + e

// Update Bitbucket commit build status to Failed  
bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED', repoSlug: "${REPO_SLUG}", commitId: "${GIT_COMMIT}")

}
```

Please **note** that GIT_COMMIT is a jenkins environment variable. I tried echo on these variables and see correct values as expected however passing them to this plugin does not seem to be working.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you succeed eventually?

Answer (score 0):

Please use that script:
import hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction

```
node {
    stage 'Checkout'
        notifyBitbucket('INPROGRESS')
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
    enter code here
    stage 'Build'
        bat "nuget restore \"${workspace}/PlaygroundForVaults.sln\""
        bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" restore \"${workspace}/PlaygroundForVaults.sln\""
        bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" build \"${workspace}/PlaygroundForVaults.sln\""
    stage 'UnitTests'
        bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" test \"${workspace}/PlaygroundForVaults.sln\" --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" --no-build"
        step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"**/unit_tests.xml", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
        def allTestPassed = allTestPass()
        if(allTestPassed == false)
        {
            notifyBitbucket('FAILED')
            assert false
        }
        else
        {
            notifyBitbucket('SUCCESS')
        }
}
def allTestPass() {
    def testStatus = ""
    def allTestPass = 0
    AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
    if (testResultAction != null) {
        def total = testResultAction.totalCount
        def failed = testResultAction.failCount
        def skipped = testResultAction.skipCount
        def passed = total - failed - skipped
        testStatus = "Test Status:\n  Passed: ${passed}, Failed: ${failed} ${testResultAction.failureDiffString}, Skipped: ${skipped}"
        if (failed == 0) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        }
        allTestPass = (failed == 0)
    }
    else
    {
        testStatus = "Didn't find any tests..."
        allTestPass = false
    }
    println testStatus
    return allTestPass
}
def notifyBitbucket(String state) {
    println "Notify Bitbucket With " + state + ", Commit = " + "${Commit}"
    if('SUCCESS' == state || 'FAILED' == state) {
        currentBuild.result = state         // Set result of currentBuild !Important!
    }

    notifyBitbucket commitSha1: '${Commit}', 
                    credentialsId: 'Bitbucket_PG_Global_For_Notification_User_Pass', 
                    disableInprogressNotification: false, 
                    considerUnstableAsSuccess: false, 
                    ignoreUnverifiedSSLPeer: true, 
                    includeBuildNumberInKey: false, `enter code here`
                    prependParentProjectKey: false, 
                    projectKey: '', 
                    stashServerBaseUrl: '<your server ip>:7990'
```

Comment: What does this has to do with the question? Could you provide an actual answer?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem and we fixed it this way:

```
@Library('jenkins-lib') _

def applicationName = 'my-app'
def revision = ""

pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            defaultContainer 'jnlp'
        
        }
    }
   
    stages {

        stage('Checkout repo') {
            steps {
                script {
                    container('jnlp'){
                       def vars =  git url: REPO_URL, credentialsId: REPO_CREDENTIALS_ID, branch: env.BRANCH_NAME
                       revision = vars.GIT_COMMIT
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        stage('Configure') {
            steps {
                bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'INPROGRESS', repoSlug: applicationName, commitId: revision )
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case it was about adding more information to the bitbucketStatusNotify, giving the repoSlug and the commitId is specific enough. The revision can be retrieved as it is done in the Checkout repo

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.